# How to use public key in RSA encryption C# (.net standard 2.0)

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption

I am developing a .net standard(.net standard 2.0) library.

I have a public key, which is created in server side and I have received it by an api call.

Now I have a string to be encrypted using RSA algorithm . Also, I have to use this public key while encrypting the string which I have.

I went through various samples, but nothing helped.

Tried this one [RSA public key encryption in C#](https://gist.github.com/zachbonham/3692542)

But got error "Operation is not supported on this platform." .

Tried [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/75a48f/rsa-algorithm-with-C-Sharp2/) one, but couldn't find a way to use public key which I have recieved from server.

Here is the latest code which I have tried . I am not sure how and where to use my public key string .

```
static public byte[] Encryption(byte[] Data, RSAParameters RSAKey, bool DoOAEPPadding)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] encryptedData;
            using (RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                RSA.ImportParameters(RSAKey);
                encryptedData = RSA.Encrypt(Data, DoOAEPPadding);
            }
            return encryptedData;
        }
        catch (CryptographicException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }
    static public byte[] Decryption(byte[] Data, RSAParameters RSAKey, bool DoOAEPPadding)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] decryptedData;
            using (RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                RSA.ImportParameters(RSAKey);
                decryptedData = RSA.Decrypt(Data, DoOAEPPadding);
            }
            return decryptedData;
        }
        catch (CryptographicException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Here i can see `RSAKey` but it doesn't accept string input.

Can anyone guide me with some samples, through which i can encrypt and decrypt a simple text, with the public which i have.

Thanks,
Noorul.

Comment: _I went through various samples, but nothing helped._ Is not a helpful description. If these examples didn't help you, why should other examples help? So please describe precisely what you tried and what the problem was. Apart from that, some important information is missing, e.g. which .NET version are you using and what is the format of the key.

Comment: @Topaco edited with links which I have tried . Hope this explains my situation.

Comment: Please post your most recent code, otherwise there is nothing here to fix. Still missing the key format.

Comment: Posted recent code , which I have tried .

Comment: Possible solutions depend on the key format (you can also post a test key of the same format). As long as you don't specify that, you will probably have to find the solution yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below you find a full working code that encrypts a string with a RSA public key in XML-encoding and decrypts the ciphertext with a RSA private key (as well in XML encoding). The ciphertext is encoded in base64. Here is a link to an online compiler to see the code running: https://repl.it/@javacrypto/CpcCsharpRsaEncryptionOaepSha1String#main.cs

output:

```
RSA 2048 encryption OAEP SHA-1 string
plaintext: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog

* * * encrypt the plaintext with the RSA public key * * *
ciphertextBase64: lFZwBN5SnlqAKEYktjjTmDUyIAFA86CDIrOyPeRLVXLIManP6wTUgZ3NBSYynfgwXTmVzhPQL3wZ6kngWIgVbl1sMOSiTt6BOvop5HwEU6ejUOrhgDzuxSnA4e8txNG0X8NZ4kt1bzE42gHlbjxHG+CYawAVYECPMyZ4Jc/n7qH8McsUh3n/KUOB2h5R6DULjf2Qfl4aQHppbEeECNmpSFJFUSu3iGBI7hacHbb+1myyLteS1o3FiBuSVbG+L7h8DEokbhE5yVTwamFF+qM+/HTWeGfE+CGC6Kb8cAucP7Zoov6e+Gr7aFYMvhrWjTvApzMBu5XD0j3JzxQD9OmA8g==

* * * decrypt the ciphertext with the RSA private key * * *
ciphertextReceivedBase64: lFZwBN5SnlqAKEYktjjTmDUyIAFA86CDIrOyPeRLVXLIManP6wTUgZ3NBSYynfgwXTmVzhPQL3wZ6kngWIgVbl1sMOSiTt6BOvop5HwEU6ejUOrhgDzuxSnA4e8txNG0X8NZ4kt1bzE42gHlbjxHG+CYawAVYECPMyZ4Jc/n7qH8McsUh3n/KUOB2h5R6DULjf2Qfl4aQHppbEeECNmpSFJFUSu3iGBI7hacHbb+1myyLteS1o3FiBuSVbG+L7h8DEokbhE5yVTwamFF+qM+/HTWeGfE+CGC6Kb8cAucP7Zoov6e+Gr7aFYMvhrWjTvApzMBu5XD0j3JzxQD9OmA8g==
decryptedData: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

**Security warning**: the code uses hard coded RSA [sample] keys for demonstration only. The code has no exception handling and is for educational purpose only.

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

class RsaEncryptionOaepSha1 {
    static void Main() {
    Console.WriteLine("RSA 2048 encryption OAEP SHA-1 string");
    string dataToEncryptString = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
    Console.WriteLine("plaintext: " + dataToEncryptString);

    // # # # usually we would load the private and public key from a file or keystore # # #
    // # # # here we use hardcoded keys for demonstration - don't do this in real programs # # #
    string filenamePrivateKeyXml = "privatekey2048.xml";
    string filenamePublicKeyXml = "publickey2048.xml";

        try {
      // encryption
        Console.WriteLine("\n* * * encrypt the plaintext with the RSA public key * * *");
        //string publicKeyLoad = loadRsaPublicKeyPem();
        // use this in production
        string publicKeyLoad = File.ReadAllText(filenamePublicKeyXml);
        byte[] dataToEncrypt = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dataToEncryptString);
        string ciphertextBase64 = Base64Encoding(rsaEncryptionOaepSha1(publicKeyLoad, dataToEncrypt));
        //string ciphertextBase64 = "";
        Console.WriteLine("ciphertextBase64: " + ciphertextBase64);

        // transport the encrypted data to recipient

        // receiving the encrypted data, decryption
        Console.WriteLine("\n* * * decrypt the ciphertext with the RSA private key * * *");
        string ciphertextReceivedBase64 = ciphertextBase64;
        Console.WriteLine("ciphertextReceivedBase64: " + ciphertextReceivedBase64);
        //string privateKeyLoad = loadRsaPrivateKeyPem();
        // use this in production
        string privateKeyLoad = File.ReadAllText(filenamePrivateKeyXml);
        byte[] ciphertextReceived = Base64Decoding(ciphertextReceivedBase64);
        byte[] decryptedtextByte = rsaDecryptionOaepSha1(privateKeyLoad, ciphertextReceived);
        Console.WriteLine("decryptedData: " + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedtextByte, 0, decryptedtextByte.Length));
        }
        catch(ArgumentNullException) {
            Console.WriteLine("The data was not RSA encrypted");
        }
    }

  public static byte[] rsaEncryptionOaepSha1(string publicKeyXml, byte[] plaintext) {
    RSACryptoServiceProvider RSAalg = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);
        RSAalg.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
        RSAalg.FromXmlString(publicKeyXml);
        return RSAalg.Encrypt(plaintext, true);
  }

  public static byte[] rsaDecryptionOaepSha1(string privateKeyXml, byte[] ciphertext) {
    RSACryptoServiceProvider RSAalg = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);
        RSAalg.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
        RSAalg.FromXmlString(privateKeyXml);
    return RSAalg.Decrypt(ciphertext, true);
  }

  static string Base64Encoding(byte[] input) {
    return Convert.ToBase64String(input);
  }

  static byte[] Base64Decoding(String input) {
    return Convert.FromBase64String(input);
  }

  public static string loadRsaPublicKeyPem() {
    return "<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>8EmWJUZ/Osz4vXtUU2S+0M4BP9+s423gjMjoX+qP1iCnlcRcFWxthQGN2CWSMZwR/vY9V0un/nsIxhZSWOH9iKzqUtZD4jt35jqOTeJ3PCSr48JirVDNLet7hRT37Ovfu5iieMN7ZNpkjeIG/CfT/QQl7R+kO/EnTmL3QjLKQNV/HhEbHS2/44x7PPoHqSqkOvl8GW0qtL39gTLWgAe801/w5PmcQ38CKG0oT2gdJmJqIxNmAEHkatYGHcMDtXRBpOhOSdraFj6SmPyHEmLBishaq7Jm8NPPNK9QcEQ3q+ERa5M6eM72PpF93g2p5cjKgyzzfoIV09Zb/LJ2aW2gQw==</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>";
  }

  public static string loadRsaPrivateKeyPem() {
    return "<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>8EmWJUZ/Osz4vXtUU2S+0M4BP9+s423gjMjoX+qP1iCnlcRcFWxthQGN2CWSMZwR/vY9V0un/nsIxhZSWOH9iKzqUtZD4jt35jqOTeJ3PCSr48JirVDNLet7hRT37Ovfu5iieMN7ZNpkjeIG/CfT/QQl7R+kO/EnTmL3QjLKQNV/HhEbHS2/44x7PPoHqSqkOvl8GW0qtL39gTLWgAe801/w5PmcQ38CKG0oT2gdJmJqIxNmAEHkatYGHcMDtXRBpOhOSdraFj6SmPyHEmLBishaq7Jm8NPPNK9QcEQ3q+ERa5M6eM72PpF93g2p5cjKgyzzfoIV09Zb/LJ2aW2gQw==</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent><P>/8atV5DmNxFrxF1PODDjdJPNb9pzNrDF03TiFBZWS4Q+2JazyLGjZzhg5Vv9RJ7VcIjPAbMy2Cy5BUffEFE+8ryKVWfdpPxpPYOwHCJSw4Bqqdj0Pmp/xw928ebrnUoCzdkUqYYpRWx0T7YVRoA9RiBfQiVHhuJBSDPYJPoP34k=</P><Q>8H9wLE5L8raUn4NYYRuUVMa+1k4Q1N3XBixm5cccc/Ja4LVvrnWqmFOmfFgpVd8BcTGaPSsqfA4j/oEQp7tmjZqggVFqiM2mJ2YEv18cY/5kiDUVYR7VWSkpqVOkgiX3lK3UkIngnVMGGFnoIBlfBFF9uo02rZpC5o5zebaDIms=</Q><DP>BPXecL9Pp6u/0kwY+DcCgkVHi67J4zqka4htxgP04nwLF/o8PF0tlRfj0S7qh4UpEIimsxq9lrGvWOne6psYxG5hpGxiQQvgIqBGLxV/U2lPKEIb4oYAOmUTYnefBCrmSQW3v93pOP50dwNKAFcGWTDRiB/e9j+3EmZm/7iVzDk=</DP><DQ>rBWkAC/uLDf01Ma5AJMpahfkCZhGdupdp68x2YzFkTmDSXLJ/P15GhIQ+Lxkp2swrvwdL1OpzKaZnsxfTIXNddmEq8PEBSuRjnNzRjQaLnqjGMtTBvF3G5tWkjClb/MW2q4fgWUG8cusetQqQn2k/YQKAOh2jXXqFOstOZQc9Q0=</DQ><InverseQ>BtiIiTnpBkd6hkqJnHLh6JxBLSxUopFvbhlR37Thw1JN94i65dmtgnjwluvR/OMgzcR8e8uCH2sBn5od78vzgiDXsqITF76rJgeO639ILTA4MO3Mz+O2umrJhrkmgSk8hpRKA+5Mf9aE7dwOzHrc8hbj8J102zyYJIE6pOehrGE=</InverseQ><D>hXGYfOMFzXX/vds8HYQZpISDlSF3NmbTCdyZkIsHjndcGoSOTyeEOxV93MggxIRUSjAeKNjPVzikyr2ixdHbp4fAKnjsAjvcfnOOjBp09WW4QCi3/GCfUh0w39uhRGZKPjiqIj8NzBitN06LaoYD6MPg/CtSXiezGIlFn/Hs+MuEzNFu8PFDj9DhOFhfCgQaIgEEr+IHdnl5HuUVrwTnIBrEzZA/08Q0Gv86qQZctZWoD9hPGzeAC+RSMyGVJw6Ls8zBFf0eysB4spsu4LUom/WnZMdS1ls4eqsAX+7AdqPKBRuUVpr8FNyRM3s8pJUiGns6KFsPThtJGuH6c6KVwQ==</D></RSAKeyValue>";
  }

}
```